# How to index the landing page of many URLs using Solr?

Tags: solr

I have a list of thousands of Web URLs (originated from bookmarks). I have a need to be able to search the landing page of these URLs. I don't need the web crawler function but I need the de-duplication function.

I'm new to solr and try to figure out the simplest way to create the index. I'm thinking about using SimplePostTool that accepts multi URLs as its parameters. However, I have difficulty understanding how to use the de-duplication with this SimplePostTool.

Is there any other method to do this indexing? 
Appreciate for any hints.
Thanks.

Comment: What action do you want to perform for de-duplication, i.e., overwrite the old doc, discard the new doc etc.?

Comment: Just overwrite...

Comment: You can simply set the uniqueKey to your url field in the schema file and solr will automatically overwrite the doc

Comment: Ok. I'm new to solr so I try to use the SimplePostTool because it doesn't need schema file. Now if I need to use it any way, is there any sample schema file for thing that I need to do i;e: indexing landing page of multiple URLs? Thanks

Comment: The schema file does not have anything to do with the post tool. You'll find the schema file in your core/collection directory if you're using solr in standalone mode or in your zookeeper instance if you're using cloud mode. Take a look here:https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Documents%2C+Fields%2C+and+Schema+Design for more info

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'll have a look at it.